# mysql search query and display all similar users

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have small question on mysql search query i need to make a search query php scripting with displaying all similar name , eg: if 100 similar names are found in the results the 100 results must show.

Here is my script of search query system.

```
$result = mysql_Query("SELECT user FROM `UserData` WHERE user LIKE '%$username%'") or die(mysql_error());
        $fetch = mysql_num_rows($result);           

        if( $fetch > 0 )
        {                   
            $resultgg = mysql_Query("SELECT user FROM `theusers` WHERE user LIKE '%$username%' ORDER BY `user` ASC LIMIT 500") or die(mysql_error());
            $row = mysql_fetch_row($resultgg);
            $users = $row[0];               
            echo "$users";                  
        }
               }
    else 
    {
            echo "<br><b>Please Enter Valid Username!</b>";
    }
```

Please Help me.

Comment: Pretty sure mysql_Query is supposed to be mysql_query

Comment: What result are you getting, when you run the current code?

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_fetch_row()
```

returns only *1* column of the resultset (see PHP docs). You need to iterate through the rows.

[Visit the PHP documentation for mysql_fetch_row](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php)